# Formatting Excel Data Labels based on Data Point

Tags: excel, formatting

I have multiple data points on a graph in excel (2016), I have set the color of the data points to be 'Automatic' so that all the points in the same series are a different color.
I have labels for these data points but I would like the labels to have a border that's the same color as the data point itself.
I don't want to manually change each label to match the data point.

I tried the formatting options available in the formatting tab, but there is no option to match color. I am not experienced in VB but willing to learn

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.